# iOS push notification listener?

Tags: ios, push-notification, listener, utility

I don't know if it is possible to write a utility application that runs on background.
if it is possible, how to read all push notifications?Does Apple allow it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

**Push Notifications** 
This is the most friendly for battery and device resources; requires a server-side implementation of the notification system, though. --- Possibly not what you are currently looking for, but definitely the "best" solution when it comes to instant notifications and network-loss handling.

**Running the App in the background** 
Apps can run in the background and keep checking a server for new data, etc... However, it is not guranteed that the application may run for a long time since iOS's process manager might put your App to sleep or quit it unexpectedly. --- Possibly comes closer to what you are looking for and might work for basic tests; but is not very reliable.

**Supporting Multitasking** 
This is obviously the "best" way to do it. Implement support for multitasking and have iOS wake up your application whenever traffic is detected. This can be done using the "voip" background-mode.

The UIApplication delegate has the method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

which you need to implement. This receives the notification when the app is running.

If your app is not currently running and a notification is received then your app can be launched with

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood. i meant to read all notifications that other apps sent. my app doesnt send notification. i want to read other  installed apps actions (recieved mail, fb, twitter, instagram.. notifications etc...)

Comment: as far i know its not possible. Even if we wanted do it in background you cant execute a code more than 10 min in background.